# Error using selenium with chromedriver on raspberry Pi 3 - Raspbian Jessie

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, raspbian

I try to execute this ::

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
import schedule
from datetime import datetime

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/pi/Documents/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://google.com')
time.sleep(5)
```

Here is the error I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/pi/Documents/chromedriver')  # Optional arg$
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Is there anybody who know how to solve it ?
I tried also with firefox and xvfb with no success for the moment.

Here is the path define in '.bashrc' :

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/Documents/chromedriver
```

Comment: I get the same error when trying to use the chromedriver on raspian pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but I set up my selenium environment on my Ubuntu machines (raspberry pi should be similar enough) using this helper script. Install setupdriver.sh

```
echo "removing chromium-browser"
sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser
rm ~/.config/chromium/ -rf
echo "removing chrome"
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
rm ~/.config/google-chrome/ -rf
sudo apt-get install libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
echo "installing Chrome"
echo "getting libxi6"
sudo apt-get install libxi6 libgconf-2-4
echo "getting chromedriver2.27"
wget -N https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.27/chromedriver_linux64.zip
echo "unzipping chromedriver2.27"
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
echo "exe chromedriver"
chmod +x chromedriver
echo "removing /usr/local/share/chromedriver"
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/chromedriver
echo "removing /usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
echo "removing /usr/bin/chromedriver"
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/chromedriver
echo "moving chromedriver to local/share"
sudo mv -f chromedriver /usr/local/share/chromedriver
echo "linking to bin"
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
echo "linking to local bin"
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

so try copying that code into a shell file. `chmod +x` the file, then `sh filename.sh`  or you can copy type each step directly into terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your script, I tried but doesn't solve the problem, still the same error

Comment: Seems like chromedriver is not working on ARM architectures... so bad :(

Comment: I found this driver and it works https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v1.6.0/chromedriver-v2.21-linux-armv7l.zip

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this legacy driver:

https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v1.6.0/chromedriver-v2.21-linux-armv7l.zip

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post, [the command to install chromedriver](https://ivanderevianko.com/2020/01/selenium-chromedriver-for-raspberrypi) is the follwing:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

and you will have 74.0.3729.157 version of ChromeDriver available in the system.